SSL/TLS Handshake Failure in Spring Boot Application Running in Docker Container
I'm encountering an SSL/TLS handshake failure issue while running a Spring Boot application inside a Docker container. The authentication server fails to communicate with external OAuth2 providers (e.g., Kakao, Naver) and logs the error Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. This problem does not occur in the local environment with the same configuration.
Environment:

Docker
Spring Boot 3.2.4
Java 17 (Eclipse Temurin)
Alpine Linux based Docker image

Dockerfile:
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache dos2unix ca-certificates
COPY gradlew .
RUN dos2unix gradlew
RUN chmod +x gradlew
COPY gradle gradle
COPY build.gradle .
COPY settings.gradle .
RUN chmod +x ./gradlew

RUN ./gradlew --version
RUN ./gradlew dependencies

COPY src src
RUN ./gradlew build --no-daemon

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine as jre-build
COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/*.jar /app/app.jar
RUN jar xf /app/app.jar
RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/jdeps \
    --ignore-missing-deps \
    --multi-release 17 \
    --recursive \
    --print-module-deps \
    --class-path 'BOOT-INF/lib/*' \
    /app/app.jar > /app/deps.info

RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink \
    --add-modules $(cat /app/deps.info) \
    --strip-debug \
    --no-man-pages \
    --no-header-files \
    --compress=2 \
    --output /javaruntime

FROM alpine:3.15
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk
ENV PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djavax.net.debug=all"

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates openjdk11-jre-headless

RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY --from=jre-build /javaruntime $JAVA_HOME
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=jre-build /app/app.jar /app/app.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]

Docker Compose:
version: '3'
services:
  authentication:
    image: sunwoo3856/authentication:latest
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djavax.net.debug=all"
    depends_on:
      - config-server
      - db

Log Message:
2024-05-22T09:10:14.955Z  INFO 1 --- [authentication] [nio-8084-exec-4] c.c.c.d.o.h.OAuth2LoginFailureHandler    : Failed to complete the social login. Error message: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST request for "https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/token": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Added -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djavax.net.debug=all to JAVA_OPTS
Added CA certificates to Java Keystore
Customized RestTemplate to apply SSL settings
Checked SSL/TLS debug logs
Verified Docker network settings
Confirmed that the same SSL/TLS configuration works fine in the local environment

Despite these attempts, the handshake_failure error persists only within the Docker container. What additional steps can I take to diagnose or resolve this issue?
Thank you for your help.
